# Google Play Developer Console updating problems, normal?

Tags: android, google-play

I deployed my app to Google Play a week ago, and frequently check my developer console to analyze the stats. The problem is, sometimes it doesn't update even after 24 hours. For example, it has been two days since any of the figures in my console have changed, and this is becoming very frustrating.

Is this normal? Any advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - there are various occasions in which this seems to be the scenario. Try to see if you have any changes in the other statistics that are reported i.e. number of active device installs/uninstalls per day, etc. I believe the stats would not be updated at a frequency less than 24 hours.

At times, when you login to the console, you might see some messages from Play Market informing about some issues with the updates. I have seen that a few times in the last year.

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE:  Stats have been lagging by as much as three days plus at times lately (September, 2015).  Recently, there was a message apologizing for the delay and saying that stats would be updated soon; and they were, a day later.  So if you have a new app and are wondering where your stats are, relax - "soon come" as they say in the Carribbean.

One can imagine what might be the reason for this.  With well over a million apps on the Google Play store, grinding through all of that data probably takes some significant time.

Previous answer:

My own recent experience nine months later than this question was posted is that stats actually update on my Developer Dashboard a little before 6:00am PST, and that the updated stats reflect what was true at some point midnight or later of that day (i.e., between zero and six hours earlier).

I can imagine some process that starts at midnight and grinds through all of the hundreds of thousands of apps, and for each one takes a snapshot and posts it.  So if your app happens to be on the front end of the list for that process, maybe you get your update closer to midnight, and if not, maybe not.  Mine always come in a little before 6:00am.

I'd also note that the report of how many instances of my apps have been installed that appears on the public page for the apps themselves seems to lag the stats available in my developer dashboard by as much as five days (so far).  Maybe these are done weekly on a certain day or maybe there is a specific delay; I don't know, but there is definitely a delay that can be as long as five days and perhaps longer.

I have some circumstantial evidence that the details pages are updated once per WEEK but am still monitoring this and will report back when my second update occurs.  As of now, one app's page is about five days behind, so I'll post back here when it updates again, and will indicate how current the data is at that time.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an update with such complete information.  I just released my first app and have been checking back every 15 minutes to see if it updated (I'm excited; sue me).  You just saved me an entire day of complete frustration.  :)

Comment: I released my app 7 days ago and my stats are 6 days behind, and the stats from 6 days ago are wrong because it is showing 0 downloads while I know of at least 2 downloads from that day.

Comment: Well make that 7 days now without new stats.

Comment: Another strange thing is that my app went from position 5 in search results for a certain critical keyword down to 35 for no apparent reason, right around the time that stats got delayed.  I'm hoping that will reverse once things get back to normal.  It's a jarring experience as it's something very important to you as a developer that appears to be influenced by factors having little to do with the quality of your app.

Comment: Yes, stats came back and several days later my search position went back up to number 4.