# Total users/active device installs & download count not update in android developer console

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my first app on Google Play about 48 hours ago...

I found that inside my Developer Console, the total number of downloads are showing 0+downloads after many downloads .and Additional Information section is not showing "Installs" field .

Anyone know is there anything wrong in publishing setting?

My app is:  0Hour Safety app- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsit.zero.hour.ui.activity

Comment: See my earlier answer to this question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060715/google-play-developer-console-updating-problems-normal/16431681#16431681

Comment: @user3256348 so after how many days did you get to see the installs and download count?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have some other form of tracking that you know you have "many downloads"?

The information on the console is not real time and takes a while to update generally. I think it updates more frequently based on the popularity of your app.